# Markov chain and mutual information

Tags: information-theory

If $X\rightarrow Y\rightarrow Z$ follow a Markov chain, then we have the following properties$$I(X;Z)\leq I(X;Y)$$  where $I$ is the mutual information expression.

Intuitvely I agree. I want to formally prove it though.

So I try

$$I(X;Z)= H(X)-H(X|Z)$$
$$I(X;Y)= H(X)-H(X|Y)$$

Do we have that $$H(X|Z) >H(X|Y)$$ because of Markov chain?

Else I don't see how one can prove it.

Comment: Almost, but you need "greater than or equal to." We have $H(X|Y) = H(X|Y,Z) \leq H(X|Z)$, where the first equality is from the Markov structure, and final inequality is because conditioning reduces entropy.

Comment: can you please write it as answer?

Comment: so I accept it, thanks @Michael

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Almost, but you need "greater than or equal to." We have:

$$ H(X|Y) = H(X|Y,Z) \leq H(X|Z) $$

where the first equality is from the Markov structure and the final inequality is because conditioning reduces entropy.

---

In more detail, to see how the Markov property works "backwards," notice that (assuming these point masses make sense):

\begin{align}
Pr[X=x|Y=y,Z=z] &= \frac{Pr[X=x, Y=y, Z=z]}{Pr[Y=y,Z=z]}  \\
&= \frac{Pr[X=x,Y=y]Pr[Z=z|X=x,Y=y]}{Pr[Y=y]Pr[Z=z|Y=y]} \\
&= \frac{Pr[X=x,Y=y]Pr[Z=z|Y=y]}{Pr[Y=y]Pr[Z=z|Y=y]} \: \: \: (*) \\
&= Pr[X=x|Y=y]
\end{align}

where equation (*) uses the Markov property $Pr[Z=z|X=x,Y=y]=Pr[Z=z|Y=y]$.

If you are more comfortable using the Markov property forwards, you could also work out that $H(X|Y)=H(X|Y,Z)$ using $H(Z|X,Y)=H(Z|Y)$ (which is the "forward" Markov property when $X\rightarrow Y \rightarrow Z$) and some other basic properties of the entropy function, like $H(A,B) = H(A) + H(B|A)$.