# Fidelity between two matrices

Tags: matrices

I'm calculating the scattering matrix whose ideal form is
$S = \left(    \begin{array}{ccc}
        0 &1 & 0 \\
        0 & 0 & 1 \\
        1 & 0 & 0
    \end{array} \right)
$.

My numerical result is however something like
$S' = \left(    \begin{array}{ccc}
        0.0155571 & 0.67857 & 0.31505 \\
        0.0141489 & 0.30954 & 0.666379 \\
        0.972694 & 0.0225014 & 0.0176157
    \end{array} \right)$.

I would like to define a fidelity function that tells how close $S'$ is to $S$; when $S' \equiv S$ the fidelity becomes unit and when $S'$ is very different from $S$ the fidelity becomes very small.

Comment: Maybe you can try mutual information? It was popular last time I was in academia. http://www.scholarpedia.org/article/Mutual_information

Comment: This one could maybe help: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1114673/markov-chain-and-mutual-information

Comment: @mathreadler: thank you, I'll have a look at it.