# Prove that something that can be learned from $S=\sum_{i=1}^n x_i$ is not less than what can be learned from $S+x_{n+1}$

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, information-theory, mutual-information

Is there a way to formally prove that whatever can be learned about any $x_i$ from $S=\sum_{i=1}^n x_i$ is certainly not less than what can be learned from $S'=S+x_{n+1}$ where $x_i$s belong to some field $\mathbb{F}$? Here learning is in the adversarial sense for cryptography -- can be any information an adversary can learn about $x_i$ which it could not have without access to $S/S'$ before.

Comment: This question is unclear? What do you mean by 'learn'?

Comment: Learning is in the adversarial sense in crypto - we can also imagine it in an information theoretic sense - information contained in $S$ about $x_i$.

Comment: Can we assume that the $x_i$ are independent? If they are not independent, the statement is not necessarily true, if I understand your notion of "learning" correctly. Consider for example $x_i = (-1)^ia$ for some $a$, that we are interested in. Then, $S_{2n} = 0$ and $S_{2n+1} = -a$, so we can learn more about $a$ with $S_{2n+1}$ as compared to $S_{2n}$

Comment: yes x_is are independent

Answer (score 1):

Esentially, we want to prove $I(X_i,S)\ge I(X_i,S')$

Let's prove it (WLOG) for $X_i=X_1$

Let $A=X_1$, $B=X_2 +X_3 + \cdots X_n$ , $C=X_{n+1}$. Assume $X_i$ are independent (hence also $A,B,C$ are).

Let $X=A$, $Y=A+B$ , $Z=A+B+C$

---

Lemma: $X\to  Y \to Z$ is a Markov chain.

Proof: $P(Z=z|Y=y,X=x)=P(X_{n+1} + y = z)=P(X_{n+1} = z -y)$

(for the last equation, recall that the variables belong to a field). Hence $P(Z|Y,X)=P(Z|Y)$. QED

---

Then, $I(X;Y)\ge I(X;Z)$ ([basic property](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1114673/markov-chain-and-mutual-information)), that is

$$ I(X_1;X_1 + X_2 + X_n) \ge I(X_1; X_1 +X_2 + \cdots X_{n+1}) $$

as expected.

Or, if you prefer $H(X|Y)\le H(X|Z)$, i.e.

$$ H(X_1 |X_1 + X_2 + X_n) \le H(X_1 | X_1 +X_2 + \cdots X_{n+1}) $$